# CSS3 Animation should stop at position 75%

Tags: css, css-animations

Is it possible to stop CSS3 Animation at 75% and should not show again at 0% or atleast make delay at 75% for 10s ? As right now when animation completed it shows on at position 0%

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: example;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

@-webkit-keyframes example {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: yellow;
    left: 200px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: blue;
    left: 200px;
    top: 200px;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: green;
    left: 0px;
    top: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please note: questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. There is a reason you are asked to also add code when adding a link to jsfiddle, please dont circumvent it - the question will attract a more solid response if it contains everything users need to answer it, without having to go to another site

Comment: There is a great formatting guide available of SO. Please refer it. You will get quick responses from the community if your question is genuine and understandable.

Comment: I've added the relevant code into your question, please remember for next time ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made couple of changes to your animation, all you need to do is duplicate your `75%` animation twice and later use [`animation-fill-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) property and set it to `forwards` to halt the animation at the last position.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/r6jpxt84/3/)

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;

    /* add these properties */
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {background-color:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
    50%  {background-color:blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
    75%  {background-color:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
    /* add the below one */
    100%  {background-color:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
}
```

Comment: @Nouman You can mark the answer as correct by clicking on the tick besides my answer so that it may help future visitors as well